# When is a comment obsolete?

Tags: support, comment-flags

When is a comment obsolete, if [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628943/203657) is not?

Context: the answer had been link-only, I commented it to nudge the author into expanding the post. Today I cleaned up some comments, detected the author complied, deleted my nudge and flagged the other (similar content) comment as obsolete - which was declined.

Was it wrong to flag? Was it the wrong reason? What else to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I declined your flag.

It was a fat-finger.

I realized it right as I was hitting 'dismiss'.

We make mistakes. Sorry about that.

In general, 
Not all comment flags need to be handled by a moderator. We sometimes dismiss them because we don't need to handle it -- if multiple members of the community flag a comment, it gets handled automatically.

So, when you get a comment flag dismissed, it may not be because you're wrong, but because a moderator doesn't need to handle it -- the community can.

Another tidbit: Once we dismiss a comment flag, we can't find it in our recent moderator actions, so there's no ability for us to revisit a flag we dismiss.

Comment: thanks for the info :-) but darn, why-o-why can't I accept it right away .. ;)

Comment: `So, when you get a comment flag dismissed, it may not be because you're wrong, but because a moderator doesn't need to handle it -- the community can.`... Not sure I follow this one.  Even if you decline the flag, enough community flags will delete the comment anyway?  Or do you just mean because the hypothetical flag shouldn't have been a mod flag as the community should deal with it via other means?

Comment: @psubsee2003 We don't decline comment flags (there's no 'decline' ability, only 'dismiss').  You're correct, for comments, if enough members of the community flag it, it'll be deleted, regardless of our action.

Comment: +1 for having the yarbles to own it straight up

Comment: *"Once we dismiss a comment flag, we can't find it in our recent moderator actions, so there's no ability for us to revisit a flag we dismiss."* Whaa?! Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, what happens then to our flag count?  Doesn't that end up decreasing our ability to flag further comments, or does the auto-accept after enough flags occur remove the 'unhelpful' flag?

Comment: @Joe I don't know. I do know that a declined flag here or there won't hurt you, but having en-masse declines will.  I suppose that's one reason to check your flags if you start getting a lot of flags declined.