# Flagged a "close reason" comment obsolete after it was closed - Flag declined

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

Our new close reasons are so well worded that I've seen quite a few people simply copy-pasting them into the comments when the vote to close. In fact, I do it myself when I think it's appropriate.

But after the question has been put on hold, it seems like the comment becomes redundant and a candidate for an "obsolete" flag.

I flagged the "close reason" comment on this question, but it was declined:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411456/back-reference-tag-epsilon-editor

Should we not be flagging these sorts of comments as obsolete?

(I was under the impression that the obsolete flag [could be used fairly liberally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156127/is-it-ok-to-casually-flag-comments-as-obsolete), but perhaps I've misunderstood its proper usage.)

**UPDATE:**
The comment has been deleted.

Comment: Is this (flagging comments as obsolete) something that is desired more of is done?  I hadn't noticed it until a few questions about it the last few days.  Anyway, from the [other thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189359/when-is-a-comment-obsolete) on this, it's possible the moderator declined it because a few other flags will cause it to be implemented automatically.  (I'm not sure if that removes the 'not helpful' flag, though.)

Comment: FYI, I flagged that comment, and it was marked helpful.  Not sure if related to this thread or not (or even, if it was automatically helpful from others doing same).  :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, copying the close reasons to a comment prior to actual closure comes with its own set of problems.  I'm not sure that preemptively pasting the reason you cast your close vote is all that helpful.  What if the question never closes?

In any event, saying the same thing twice on the same post does seem a bit redundant.  But note that when a mod dismisses a comment flag (meaning he has chosen just to leave the comment there without deleting it), it *automatically gets declined.*

For my own part, I only bother to go through the comments queue and delete comments when they are clearly not being helpful, which is not the case here.  And I only do *that* if there are no post flags to take care of.  In other words, comment flags are considered the lowest priority on the flag hierarchy.

Comment: So a comment by the OP expounding on their question, which is then incorporated into the question and thus redundant, is obsolete, but a comment by a user explaining their close vote reason, which becomes redundant when the question is closed for that very reason, is not obsolete? Or do you mean that this is more of a "not worth my time" sort of flag? In which case, should I flag these as obsolete anyway and let the community handle it, or should I also not waste my time on these?

Comment: It's a redundant comment on a dead question that's probably going to be deleted anyway.