# What do mods see when reviewing my comment flag?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, comment-flags

I would like to know what mods see when reviewing my comment flags.

Do they just see the comment in isolation, or do they see the post and/or the other comments as well?

If they only see the comment in isolation, if they can't see the validity of the flag from just that, do they go look at the post to see if it's valid, just approve it, or just decline it?

I guess this mainly applies to "obsolete" flags, but may apply to the others as well.

**Motivation**

I'd like to know the above in order to perhaps change my flag reasons a bit to get less of my flags declined (not that I think my flagging history is all that bad currently, but it can always be better), and be a bit more comfortable with what to do when.

As an example, I flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302140/how-to-delete-a-row-column-from-a-sparse-table-in-constant-time#comment28619104_19302140) (at least I assume it was that one, my flagging history only links to the post) as obsolete, but the flag was declined. Given that the @ reply was to my comment, which was deleted before the flag, it should be easy to see that it's obsolete by looking at the other comments (perhaps by searching for the username).

Should I have used a custom reason here, or was that flag fine (I realize that [mistakes happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189359/when-is-a-comment-obsolete))?

(I forgot about my reply to that comment, which possibly changes things a bit, but not my main question).

Some generic when to use a standard reason and when to use a custom flag advice (for borderline cases) would also be appreciated, specifically related to comment flags, and mainly related to the "obsolete" flag.

Comment: Found screenshots [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147313/152859) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164407/152859) - is that what you're after?

Answer (score 13):

We see the title of the post and the comments that are flagged.  If we choose to go to the post, we'll see all the comments.   Unless there's a compelling reason to go to the post, we normally do not.

Compelling reasons include:

- A comment flag that asks us to clean up the flagged comment as well as other comments
- multiple comment flags on a post
- What appears to be a back and forth that is getting negative

If I think a comment still has merit, I'll let it stay around.  Here's the criteria I use to see if a comment should be deleted:

- The reason for the comment flag isn't disputable by a normal person
- The comment is years old on a post that is years old and has been flagged
- The comment is part of a conversation between two users that is only tangential to the post
- I can see no useful reason for the comment to still exist (examples include "+1" and its ilk)

In your case, the comment is not obsolete. While the beginning part, "Oh I see" is referring to a deleted comment, there's still a substantial part of the comment that has relevance and has not been addressed. For it to be obsolete, one of the following three conditions would have to exist:

1. The OP or another poster would have addressed the reason why that tag was not added.
2. Someone added the tag to the post.
3. The [time-complexity] tag no longer exists.

None of these have happened, ergo the comment is not 'obsolete'.

Comment: It's also worth noting that we cannot see *who* cast a comment flag like we could on a post.

Comment: (a) Oh right, I forgot to mention that I replied explaining why the tag should not be added (at least I did as far as I remember). Does this change things? (b) From how I read this, it would be better to leave my comments there and flag the entire conversation (comment by comment) instead. Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 4):

In the flag view, we see the comment in isolation. In case the context is not clear, we can expand that view to see the rest of the post, including other answers and the question.

I don't know in which site you're referring, some sites may be busier than others, and moderators may not always take the full time and review every post individually