# More attention needed to prevent non-constructive answers and comments

Tags: support, moderation, comment-flags, abuse

Lately, I have been getting a lot of critical responses to my questions, and absolutely no help whatsoever. Often users are responding with questions as to why I asked the question, and also links to other questions that may be relevant to my question, but do not specifically address it. I am also flagging these comments and answers, but it doesn't seem to promote any relevant answers. Is this a known dynamic issue of Stack Overflow, and are the moderators being proactive about enforcing a more helpful community?

I have recently flagged some comments and answers, however I'm unsure what happens "behind the scenes". What happens once a flag on a comment is raised? Who deals with the flags? What are the possible outcomes?

Comment: Could you give some examples. Rude comments exist but so do blunt but helpful comments

Comment: This is an ongoing issue that has no easy solution.

Comment: Generally, yes @Pëkka. But let's see what the background of this particular case is first.

Comment: I link to other questions all the time that seem to be relevant, especially for those folks who *don't do some research first.*  It's up to the OP to figure out whether or not they are actually relevant.

Comment: I wouldn't say they were directly harassing, but seem to be excruciatingly not constructive, condescending, and really make me reluctant to return to any Stack site for answers. I understand that is hard, but it seems that no one is taking the initiative to let people know that this behavior is not welcome. I have flagged more than enough comments and answers, yet I continue to get beleaguered by users who are not willing to help, but are just there to criticize and make my questions seem insignificant.

Comment: Sounds like you *are* getting constructive comments.  Knowing some context about why a person is asking a question, and getting a better understanding for why they're trying to do what they're asking about, or how they plan to use the solution, can be enormously helpful in many cases, especially where there are several approaches, some of which may, and some of which may not, be appropriate given the specific context you're in.  Linking to related questions, even if they are not duplicates, is also constructive.  It can help you come closer to an answer, even if it doesn't provide one fully.

Comment: Going through your questions, I don't see any evidence of any of this. Did you happen to delete them?

Comment: You've asked just four questions in the last year, and none of them have comments or answers that match your description above. Exactly what are you asking about?

Comment: No I didn't remove any questions.

Comment: So the comments were removed?

Comment: Are you going to provide some examples, then?

Comment: Relevant or related links are definitely not a problem.  Even if they aren't useful to you, they may be useful to someone else.  You have to understand that questions & answers serve everyone, not just you, so if it could help point someone in the right direction, it has value .  Rude & non-constructive comments however are a different story and should be deleted, but they can be often mistaken for blunt to the point comments.  As other have said, can you provide some specific examples.

Comment: The problem is they aren't relevant. To say that a related link is 5% relevant does not mean it addresses the question. Often these links are upvoted by someone else, yet they don't address my question at all.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh if they aren't relevant to you, then ignore them.  Like I said, someone included it to try to be helpful to someone.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Do they hurt? Is your question closed as a duplicate of them? If not they are just background that might be interesting (assuming they are related at all)

Comment: @psubsee2003 It's my question. It's inherently relevant to me. Anyhow, obviously this is not a question worth addressing. Still have not fully answered my question, but you guys have offered up a lot of criticism "are the moderators (if such a thing exist) being proactive about enforcing a more helpful community?" People don't ask question expecting criticism. That's not how it works.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh We're not going to be able to answer until you give an example. But largely moderators respond to flags rather than actively patrolling

Comment: @ChrisWalsh show me the problem and we'll tell you if we're doing something about it. There have been plenty of discussions on rudeness, snark, unfriendliness and what not. Are they tolerated? No. Are moderators and users doing something about it? Yes. But as to your specific problem, I still see no examples. So I don't know if anything is missing from what we could/should be doing.

Comment: Sometimes, criticism is what a question needs, no matter what the asker expects. Sometimes, not. It really depends on the particular situation.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh there are moderators and they do delete rude and unconstructive comments, but the reason everyone is asking for examples is we are trying to get a better idea of what you think is an unhelpful comment.  Moderators do not (and physically cannot) read every single question due to the volume.  Because of that Stack Exchange is community moderated.  If you see something you don't like you can flag it, but it doesn't mean a mod will delete it.  If it is rude or nonconstructive, they will delete it.

Comment: You should have seen what it was like before the enlightenment occurred.  See [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/) and [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/).

Comment: Also, FWIW, this particular question seems to be illustrative of your specific problem.  Did you really expect to get constructive feedback from the community by hand-waving about non-constructiveness without providing some examples of it?

Comment: @Robert Harvey Well, yes.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh This is an example of where constructive critism was given "provide examples" and ignored. This almost always leads to no answers

Comment: @ChrisWalsh  Maybe you should post an example of what you mean.  It will help us understand more clearly what you're concerned with.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what to expect from this site anymore. It really is an unpleasant and absolutely degrading experience. @Bart went through my questions, so I refer you to those as examples.

Comment: Software development is a *science-based activity.*  Science demands evidence.  In my experience, the people who don't fare well with their questions are the ones who don't address them with a bit of critical thinking, and who fail to provide the necessary information required to answer them. See also [ask the duck](http://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html).

Comment: @ChrisWalsh If you are unprepared to provide examples then this question is unclear. At this point I am voting to close as such

Comment: And if you're expecting to be coddled by a bunch of curmudgeons who write software for a living, well, good luck with that.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh let's back up a couple of steps... what are you looking for out of this question?  In your question, you mentioned about flagging comments you thought were unconstructive, but not getting answers.  When you flag a comment, what do you think should happen?

Comment: @RobertHarvey your responses are exactly what enables bad attitudes in this community. Simply put you're not constructive, and you are a prime example of why I asked this question in the first place. There's no excuses for a bad attitude.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Please edit your example into your question. Then I can vote to reopen and people can respond to an actual case.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh: You're absolutely right, there's no excuses.  But I have a feeling that your threshold for pain is a bit lower than mine, and you can understand why people get a little impatient when you fail to provide the information needed to make your question answerable.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Good question. I suppose I would expect some feedback from moderators as to why they did or didn't take action. A bit more transparency, if you will. I want to know what happens after I flag something, and see if certain non-constructive users are being held responsible for their lack of providing the community with valid and substantial help.

Comment: Why didn't you just ask that in the first place?   But there's no examining the responsibility issue without providing examples of where it might be failing.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh 1) You can see the results of your flag on your profile, to see which were declined and which considered helpful 2) You make it sound like other users are *obligated* to help you.  They are not.  Users are free to provide as much or as little help as they want; they are the ones volunteering their own time.  You're the one that is coming and asking for a valuable service to be provided to you for free, and yet you seem to feel that there are no obligations on your part.  That's simply not the case, and that attitude will only cause problems for you on this site.

Comment: I get a lot of this: "please provide an example!" It almost seems as if these comments are a cop out from offering any real constructive feedback, and owning up to being legitimately helpful. I wish the admins could do a text search across the entire stack, and count how many times an "example" comment shows up. It's not an approach to getting to an answer in every situation.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh That *is* real constructive feedback, so long as the user feels that an example is needed to help in their understanding of the question, which it very often is.  Even if you feel the question can be understood without an example, it is entirely appropriate for someone else to say that they personally feel an example is needed for them to understand the question.  If you feel an example isn't needed, then consider finding some other way of clarifying what it is the question is asking, while keeping in mind that providing an example is often a very effective means of doing that.

Comment: "Please provide an example" is a very constructive request, particularly when an example is necessary. This very question serves as a perfect demonstration of why an example is necessary.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Go to a question on stack overflow, and try asking [What have you tried?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic/172760#172760).  You might find that that phrase has been blocked

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey My "threshold for pain"? Is that why we come to SO? For pain? Are you kidding me?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh doing janitorial work on a community site combined with the "evil mods y u close my post" can be a bit painful over time and requires some degree of tolerance and thick skin. People who try to guide questions into improvement and leave lengthy comments get sore fingers and become more and more terse over time - some perceive this terseness as rudeness. It is sometimes important to realize that the regulars may not always be wordy and their terseness is not rudeness. If someone perceives this as rudeness and gets offended easily it can take a bit to adapt to that community.

Comment: The mention of nothing happening made us think you wanted to resolve a specific issue. It now looks like you're interested in the mechanics of it. If so have a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209551/what-do-mods-see-when-reviewing-my-comment-flag

Comment: This reads like the "helpdesk syndrome".  He just wants to drop off his question and pick up the answer 10 minutes later.  Anybody that dares ask for clarification is just inconsiderate to his needs and therefore rude.

Comment: No I don't, man. You're just making that assumption, because it makes you feel better to agree with the masses. I have waited patiently months for some of my questions to even garner a single comment. I'm just fed up with all the hacks  that come into SO, and act like they know what they're doing by having other people dump loads of sample code into question, when it's not really the proper way to answer  question.

Comment: I bet you're the type of people when the waiter asks you if you want pepper on your "hipster" salad, and you ask them for example of what kind of pepper will come out. It's not that complicated.

Comment: Does my link answer your question?

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, sort of. At this point I'm just going to bottle up my frustrations and move on. Obviously there is a majority of you who get great discussion out of this site. I apparently don't know how to use it, and don't enjoy using it, and I am sick of the lack of response, and when I do get a response it negatively effects my reputation on here, and I've been on here a long time. I don't understand this system at all, and I hate the constant criticism. -15? Nice, Screw you guys!

Comment: @ChrisWalsh If you are offended by "Show examples of wanted behaviour.", better don't even open your browser... Don't go outside as well. Are you offended by a phrase like "Do you want your steak well done or medium?". This is almost an exact equivalent of that comment.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Also, if you don't get enough attention to your questions, then 1. Try to improve it - that's what comments are trying to say, they *are* trying to help you, even if you don't realize that. 2. Attract more attention to it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144625/what-are-legitimate-ways-to-attract-attention-to-a-question. 3. If still nothing, then, well, it is not like you paid your money for a service - people just don't know the answer (or the answer is too long & hard), that's all.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh ok, well its good you've got your answer.  Try to take comments as a request for editing your question.  Even if the comment is based on a misunderstanding that *still* means the question needs editing to make it clear; perhaps not by providing the information requested but by making the question not iook like that information is missing. Downvoting of this question only began after these requests were ignored

Comment: If I understand your question correctly I would edit it to say "I have recently flagged some questions,  however I'm unsure what happens "behind the scenes" and I think knowing that would make my flagging better.  What happens once a flag on a comment is raised? Who deals with the flags? What are the possible outcomes?"

Comment: @ChrisWalsh - The question was a rant, and something we have heard *over* and *over*.  We get it, the internet isn't the friendliest place.   Learn the ropes buddy, it's just a tool

Comment: @ChrisWalsh - I'm not sure if it'll make you feel better, but I submitted a proposal to hide downvotes .. guess what? it got DV'ed to hayl -

Comment: @Adel I don't need to be told to learn the ropes. I've been swinging thru this godforesaken hell for 12 years, and honestly, if SO is trying to improve it, that's a fairly ignorant statement to make, especially about a site meant to be a help site. If I wanted to be badgered and run with little boys and girls with nasty tempers, I'll go get my answers from sleazy IRC chans or forums. At least I'd expect the insults, passive-aggressive treatments, and bad service. I used to hold SO to a higher standard. Not so much anymore. It's called PROFESSIONALISM, there's a rope you should try!

Comment: @ChrisWalsh - See, professionalism on the internet really is StackOverflow. I'm a long-time Reddit user, you should see them. oh dear is it painful sometimes.  We mess up sometimes, but all in all, Stack has *some* level above others.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh - here's my prize , **-25** : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179443/finding-a-way-to-discourage-users-from-downvoting-questions-that-have-8-dvs-al ; it took me nigh on 7 weeks to recover from self-esteem issues, but with aid of coffee and cupcake, I have *mostly* salvaged things. still bitter tho

Answer (score 18):

I'm getting the sense that this very question is a type of question that you're concerned with.

We understand that some people can be rude, and we try to flag the rude and unhelpful posts, and the moderators delete them.

But what is a lot more common is comments by people genuinely interested in answering your question, who want more information.

---

I'll use this question as an example.  You made a request to pay more attention to undesirable comments.  We've all seen various types of undesirable comments, but we do feel as that is being paid attention to.

But it's clear that you feel like you're experiencing a problem, so We're asking for an example question, so that we can understand what you think is a problem.  Without an example, what we have to do is go through your recently asked questions, and just guess what you're taking issue with, and we're afraid that we might be wrong in our guess.

---

We want to answer your question, but we have to know what's going on.  The same is true for programming questions, and examples are a very effective way of letting us know what's going on.

- When we ask for code, It's not because we want to make you do more work.  It's because we think that there might hints in your existing code that will help us answer your question.
- When we ask for an error message, It's because we think think that the error message will help us answer your question.

---

So far, you've cited this question:

[PHP __toArray() or __toObject() override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134836/php-toarray-or-toobject-override/20388797)

and you had trouble with the following comment:

> Show examples of wanted behaviour.

at the time, your question was the following:

> Is there an equivalent to get a reorganized standardized object from a
>   normal class? Something that works along the same lines as PHP's
>   __toString() override method.

Now I'm not a PHP guy, so I'll compare this to c#.  If you asked a similar question about c#, I wouldn't understand it very well.  All c# classes inherit from the `Object` class.  I would assume that you're looking to do 1 of two things

- you want to treat your class like a generic object, in which case, you'd cast it to an object
- You want a base `Object` class which is like a copy of your class, except that only has properties already defined in `Object`.  (this option doesn't make very much sense).

The most reasonable thing to assume is that maybe your output is something other than those two scenarios, so I'd be inclined to ask:

> What do you want you object to look like when you're done with it?

which is just another way of wording

> Show examples of wanted behavior.

Comment: I'm in no way against providing examples of code. And I make that effort most of the time. Logically, I think if you ask a question, then it shouldn't just be 1) question, 2) provide example, 3) get answer. What if there is no working example? How do you deal with a theoretical or abstract question? How do you deal with questions that stem from a person who is asking how to implement a particular solution, but is seeking examples of how to do it from the community? I'm not looking for direct answers all of the time, but I would like the ability to avoid having to justify why I asked a question

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Not every question always needs to have examples.  However, when a question doesn't have examples, or context, or the reader, for whatever reason, feels that there is insufficient information to provide an answer, they can ask for further information or ask clarifying questions, which is what is going on here.  You're taking constructive clarifying questions as being a problem.  They aren't a problem.  Your refusal to answer them is, and it's the reason you're not getting the answers that you want.

Comment: Second, providing examples is not the issue at hand. I asked about how the moderating community goes about keeping people who game the stack system with irrelevant and condescending comments or answers, that stray from the topic of the question. I have flagged most of this stuff, and yet these folks keep returning with the same conversations. How are the moderators dealing with this? Are they dealing with this?

Comment: Sure, if you flag it. And if you find that a particular user keeps making inappropriate comments (as in, truly inappropriate, not clarifying) then you could even opt for a custom flag stating that more clearly.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh You haven't demonstrated a problem.  You have not shown instances of irrelevant or inappropriate comments.  You've only described instances of helpful, relevant, and appropriate comments.  If/when you're able to demonstrate cases of comments that are causing problems, then we can help you understand how best to deal with them, or consider adjusting community policies/mechanisms if you can demonstrate that there is a larger problem.

Comment: Yes, I have flagged numerous comments and answers. Obviously I can't downvote, which is another issue in and of itself (as I have been at 124 points for years (really oppressive system IMO)). Most of the people with thousands of points are the same people who are non-constructive posters.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh If you're flagging constructive clarifying questions then I would hope that nothing would be done, and you're the one in the wrong.  If the comments are inappropriate, then I'd expect them to be deleted.  If you can provide some examples of inappropriate comments that you flagged and that were not dealt with, then we can actually have a real conversation here.

Comment: @servy do you not have the ability to view my posts?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh I do, and I looked through a handful of the recent ones.  I saw no inappropriate comments.  If your response to "please provide some examples of problematic comments" is "go find them yourself, I can't be bothered to do it, then you shouldn't really be surprised when people aren't jumping out of their seats to help you.  You can't even be bothered to provide a *single* example of a problematic comment.  Either they're *really* hard to find (and thus, there isn't a real problem), or you're putting insufficient effort into your own questions, based on the community's standards.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Please please please make this easy for us. If there are posts around that are problematic, point them out in your question here. Show us. I've gone through them and I don't see it. I must be overlooking something. Don't tell us to go look for it. Show us. If you do, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh  What I wrote in this answer is informed mostly because of what I saw in the comments in this very question.  Right now, We don't know what kinds of comments that you feel are condescending.  We asked for examples, so that we could know which comments those are.  I saw your reaction to the comments on this question and thought to myself "comments like that might be it"

Comment: @ChrisWalsh  When we don't know what comments you're talking about, than we can't truly tell you how the moderators handle them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134836/php-toarray-or-toobject-override/20388797#20388797 The first comment made was "show an example" WTF, there's an example in the question. Am I losing my mind here?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh You mean ["Show examples of wanted behaviour"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134836/php-toarray-or-toobject-override/20388797#comment30008198_20134836)? If so that represents an example and we can move forwards

Comment: @ChrisWalsh That comment was left on the first revision of your question http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2173b976-d8fd-4bd2-8bf9-3a388453b2e7/view-source Apparently that question was not sufficiently clear to answer.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh That's asking for an example input/output, not example code.  That is *still* not in the question.  That comment could perhaps be clearer, since you didn't understand it, but it's certainly not unconstructive, rude, or inappropriate.  Had you responded to that comment it would have become clear that you simply didn't understand it, and that user, or someone else, could help clarify what it your question is lacking, and you could have moved forward in improving the question.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh: I reviewed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134836, but I don't see anything actionable there.  I'm not at all sure what you want.

Answer (score 1):

On one of your questions I see the comment:

> Show examples of wanted behaviour.

We really, as a community, like to see code and examples. We'd like to see the question-asker has really put effort into this issue, and is genuinely stuck.

See, there have been many posts that reek of "Oh i'm too lazy to google this today, I'm hoping a SantaClause out there will give it all to me"

So that's maybe a backlash against that trend.

But Pekka hit the nail on the head :

> This is an ongoing issue that has no easy solution

Perception and mores are tough man.

Overall, don't be shaken in your journey to get stuff done

Comment: "Show examples of wanted behavior" is just as likely a clarifying question.  If someone does not understand the output, how can they know they are answering the question correctly.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Point taken , thanks!

Comment: @Adel, I appreciate your positive reinforcement, and I try to persevere through all the irrelevant chatter, but I am left with a lot of aggravating responses, and most of the time questions left unanswered. I am not asking questions as a means to set people up for failure. I just look for collaboration on the answer. If this was an issue of providing an example, which it is not, then that is being done, I assure you. I think this goes beyond examples provision. I feel that the stack model is not working in some areas, and is starting to turn into the forums of old.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh You understand how vague that sounds, without specifics all we can say is "moderators respond to flags and take action on them depending on the specific circumstances"

Comment: So I can deduct that moderators aren't doing anything substantial to quell this problem? I suppose you see the problem, but don't want to address it. Vague or not, there is a user experiencing a difficulty with this product, and having a negative user experience, and you simply passively overlook it.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Moderators are working incredibly hard every day, spending hours responding to flags. It is unfair to say they are doing nothing. If they are responding to this specific problem is seperate (and a reasonable question to ask). So ask it

Comment: @ChrisWalsh - you said `I just look for collaboration on the answer` ... In some sense, StackOverflow just isn't a stellar collaboration tool. Collaboration denotes  some back-&-forth process, something interactive. Stack works best when the user gives a question that demonstrates at least 90% of what's needed for *anyone* skilled enough to push him/her to the solution. The 10% remaining gets figured out via comments, etc. But if you do not at least show the 90% *upfront*, well good luck. Stack isn't really gonna help

Comment: Yeah that's apparently the problem. It's not been helpful to me in the least. I guess I'll remain the 1% who just doesn't understand how it works. You know something, I've never asked for an example, considering that the user is not capable of doing so. When people seek examples for well constructed questions, they do not have the experience or the skill set to fully comprehend the question being asked, so they should simply not respond. I have had people on stack come back with constructive comments, and have come away with a good experience. Unfortunately those experiences are very few.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh The one example we have was of someone asking a question so they could help you. I presume you flagged that question. All they wanted was to clear up a confusion; how exactly you wanted the function to work. No amount of moderation is going to change that (except perhaps to stop them wanting to help you), its up to you to clarify

Comment: @ChrisWalsh If someone doesn't fully comprehend the question that's being asked that *exactly* when they should be commenting.  The *point* of comments is to help readers who don't understand the question get the information they need to be able to understand the question.  If they were able to understand the question then they could just answer it.  When the question author refuses to answer constructive clarifying questions and provides not indication of helping others understand what it is that they're after, *then* it's time to just move on and ignore the question.

Comment: Look, I've worked several years as a reference librarian before I became a programmer. When patrons asked me a question, the first thing we were taught never to do was have the user provide an example. We kept asking questions back to the patron until we got a clarification from them what exactly they were looking for, and we made sure we never ever made them feel like they were asking a stupid or irrelevant question. The more time I spend on here, the more I feel like I don't want to participate in Q&A. Is that the mission of SO? Really?!

Comment: Nobody asks a perfect question! Even if you're the best in your field.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh The two fields are not identical. If you say you want a "toString()" method asking for what you want that "toString()" method to output seems reasonable

Comment: @ChrisWalsh  You weren't asked for an example implimentation.  You were asked for example output.  When you ask "`how do I sort this list: [3, 1, 5, 4, 6]`", and someone asks you for an example, what they want you to reply with is "`[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]`"

Comment: How do I sort this list `[3, 1, 5, 4, 6]`? My comments: Do you want to sort descending or ascending? Are there any other sorting criteria required (i.e. grouped, collated, etc...)? I don't need a hand-holding example. Is it too hard for you people to ask a question back?

Comment: @ChrissWalsh Well thats fine I guess. Stack exchange cares most of all about getting high quality answers to questions and its damn good at it;  that means we ask the questions that need asking and don't accept ambiguous questions. I'm not sure what exactly you want from it

Comment: Sigh, how about we conconvene tomorrow everyone.. comments are getting a bit long

Comment: @ChrisWalsh I'm just trying to get you to understand what we mean when we're asking for an example.  We're not trying to be condescending.  We're not telling you to find the answer yourself.  We are simply asking for more information

Comment: @RichardTingle It's not that good. I've found a majority of questions left unanswered, either simply ignored, or inundated with irrelevant or question-to-answer blocking tactics. I honestly don't think you have the best and the brightest offering quality responses on here. I found numerous developer blogs commenting on how much the SO model of Q&A is lacking or just plains sucks, so don't go tooting your own whistle prematurely. Yes, there are some great answers, but I find that aspect very constrained and highly inefficient. But I guess your investors think it's GREAT!

Comment: @SamIam I'm not contesting the example issue. I don't know why you keep bringing that up???????

Comment: @ChrisWalsh - StackOverflow clearly does *something* well though, it has given us a nice little environment for a old-fashion argument here :p

Comment: LOL. Well that it does.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh If you aren't contesting the example issue, than what are you trying to say?

Comment: @SamIam I am not trying to say anything. I am asking a question, therefore seeking an answer. I've said what I have to say.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh if you don't dispute that example as a bad comment then we're back to discussing **nothing**. Regardless this is probably driving Abel insane with all the notifications. If this is to continue it should be on the main question

Comment: @ChrisWalsh  Well, the answer is Yes.  Moderators do answer flags, They do delete non-constructive comments, and it IS transparent to the flagger.